# Oracle forms 6i copy an image from one folder to another and rename it using the host command

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I use Oracle 6i with Win 2003. When I try to copy an image from one folder to another and rename it using the host command, it only takes the first 8 characters of the image name, it doesn't take the entire name.

Furthermore, I googled it and found out that it should be `xcopy` instead of `copy` but when I tried `xcopy`, my Forms builder is hanging and it's not working at all. Is this because of the server version, which is 2003, or any other reason? Please help. Here is example of the code:

```
HOST('copy'||v_source||' '||v_target,NO_SCREEN);
```

Comment: *"Is this because of the server version which is 2003"*.    Perhaps. Forms 6i is over fifteen years old, and the versions of Windows is was certified for are :  [Win98/2000 , NT 4.0 , XP](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/clientsod-forms6i-086801.html)

Comment: I presume the missing space after `copy` is a typo introduced in asking your question here, otherwise that should throw an error. Can you run `xcopy` in a CMD window?

Comment: Problem solved, I just need to add cmd